# Where should I post linux questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Suppose I want to configure my home openvpn server. Where should I ask a question about it? There are many similar Stack Exchange sites for that and all of them have `openvpn` tag. Possible candidates:

- superuser
- serverfault
- ask ubuntu
- unix & linux
- network engineering

Which one should I choose?

Comment: My opinion: Superuser is for power users. You are configuring openvpn, so you aren't a power user. Serverfault is okay, although the beginners aren't really liked there and for them is everybody beginner with low repu. AskUbuntu is friendly, but dilettant and ubuntu-specific. Network engineering is small and also dilettant. unix-linux is okay for you.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Server Fault is for professional sysadmins in pro settings, the term "home server" disqualifies the question above there.

Comment: @Mat Yes, it is the surface story :-) But after collecting 8 sites into my flair I can say there was the worst the beginning (not counting MSE of course), although from so 300 repu they were friendly soon. I feel so that they haven't any possibility to know if somebody is a "professional sysadmin", and somehow they think below 300 repu on SF nobody is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go like this:

- If you're on Ubuntu, go for [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).
- If you're on another distribution, go for [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), unless you prefer [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) (you're a regular there for instance)

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) is out, you're not talking about a professional server you're operating on as a systems administrator.

[Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) isn't the place either:

> All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly OFF-topic.